# He likes eating Japanese food

Tags: articles

“what does your brother usually eat for lunch?”

> “Well, he likes eating Japanese food”
>
> “Well, he likes eating **the** Japanese food”

Can anyone tell me which sentence is correct?

Comment: This is remarkably similar to https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/471085/the-or-no-article.